# Vertical Sliding Navigation Bar

Tags: jquery, slider

I have a vertical sliding menu but there's a few things I'm missing and not sure how to do.

- I want all the sub menu items to be closed when the page load/refreshes
- When the mouse hovers over a link with sub menus it slides down and goes back up when it hovers over another link with sub menus. I need it to slide back up every time the mouse stops hovering over the link(s)

Here's the code and thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.1.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
var $ = jQuery.noConflict(); 
$(document).ready(function(){  
$("#secondpane li.menu-item").mouseover(function(){
$(this).next("li.menu_body").slideDown(500).siblings("li.menu_body").slideUp("slow");
});  
});
</script>



<div class="menu-container">
<ul id="secondpane">
<li><a href="#">home</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#">about us</a></li>
    <li class="menu_body"><ul>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">testimonials</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">full width page</a></li>
    </ul></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#">blog</a></li>
    <li class="menu_body"><ul>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">web design</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">illustrations</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">art inspiration</a></li>
    </ul></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#">portfolio</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#">contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.1.js"></script>

<style>
li {list-style: none;}
</style>

<script type='text/javascript'>
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function(){
                             $("#secondpane li.menu-item ul").hide();

                             $("#secondpane li.menu-item").hover(function(){
                                  $(this).children("ul").slideDown(500);
                             },function(){
                                  $(this).children("ul").slideUp(500);
                             });

});
</script>



<div class="menu-container">
<ul id="secondpane">
<li><a href="#">home</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#">about us</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">testimonials</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#">full width page</a></li>
    </ul></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#">blog</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">web design</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">illustrations</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">art inspiration</a></li>
    </ul></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#">portfolio</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#">contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You many find that the animations queues up you many need to modify this `$(this).children("ul").stop(true, true).slideDown(500);`  & `$(this).children("ul").stop(true, true).slideUp(500);`

Answer (score 1):

This seem to work for me!

I just added this line of code  "$("#secondpane li.menu-item").siblings("li.menu_body").hide();"

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function(){
                             $("#secondpane li.menu-item").siblings("li.menu_body").hide();
                             $("#secondpane li.menu-item").mouseover(function(){
                                            $(this).next("li.menu_body").slideDown(500).siblings("li.menu_body").slideUp("slow");
                             });
});
</script>



<div class="menu-container">
<ul id="secondpane">
<li><a href="#">home</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#">about us</a></li>
    <li class="menu_body"><ul>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">testimonials</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">full width page</a></li>
    </ul></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#">blog</a></li>
    <li class="menu_body"><ul>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">web design</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">illustrations</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">art inspiration</a></li>
    </ul></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#">portfolio</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#">contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: haha your amazing I just need it to close when you move the mouse off the link

Comment: Sorry mate cant figure out that!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the code to be like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#secondpane li.menu-item").hover(function(){
        $("li.menu_body").slideUp(500);
        $(this).next("li.menu_body").slideDown(500);
    }, function(){
        $("li.menu_body").slideUp(500);
    });

});
```